# Powershell - save output to file without "..."

Tags: powershell

I have properties in my SharePoint web application, and I'd like to save them to text file. After calling `$webApplication.Properties`, I can see something like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
SchoolSiteUrlFormat            https://www.blablablablablablabl/sites/{school}
ApplicationDatabaseListsLoc... https://blablablablablablablabla/sites/zasobys...
```

How can I direct output from that command to file, where item name and value wouldn't contain those "..." at the and full value would be saved?

Answer (score 1):

Try piping your output to `Out-File` with the *Width* parameter specified.

```
Do-Command | Out-File -width 300 -filepath "C:\temp\myoutput.log"
```

If not that, you could try piping it to `Format-List` and then `Out-File`.

Answer (score 0):

I would export it as a comma separated text file (csv). If you need to see it nicely formatted, you can then use a spreadsheet reading program (e.g. excel).

Since the property looks like it is a dictionary, you would use the `GetEnumerator()` member function to extract the values and pipe it to the `Export-Csv` commandlet. Something like this:

```
$webApplication.Properties.GetEnumerator() | select name,value | export-csv -path "properties.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```