# Powershell : Get variables from remote machine and store them in an excel file in local machine

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell

I asked this question before, but I think I didn’t explain it well: I'm working on a project that use powershell scripts: I would like to execute in a remote machine, a file named “Remote” (existed in the second picture down), that contains some variables, I’m looking to get the content of these variables when the file “Remote” is executed in the remote machine, that I can store them in a excel file in the local machine.how i can do this please?

[The first picture represent the command which will execute the file named Remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCjzY.jpg)

[The second picture represent the file remote,which contain variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeYJw.jpg)

Comment: @Ramhound i tried to store the results of the file that i want to execute in a variable using :                                                                              $result= invoke-command -computername (hostname) -filepath (the path of the file that i want to be executed in the remote machine)      the $result is stored in the local machine,but i can"t get the content of the variable executed in that file!

Comment: We are not a script writing service, so you will have to provide what you have attempted (within he question itself), if you want anyone to seriously look at your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing Data from a remote session:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost -Credential (Get-Credential) | Out-Null
$a = Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ScriptBlock {
    $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE | Out-String
}
$b = Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ScriptBlock {
    "Test Data"
}
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

As you can see in the screenshot below... the variables `$a` and `$b` get populated with info from the remote PSSession (which can be to any machine with [PowerShell Remoting Enabled](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849694.aspx))

[image]

This should give you what you need - you can then export any content you like to text files, CSV files etc using the `Set-Content`, `Export-CSV` and various other cmdlets/functions.

Comment: Sir,i edited my request,please can you read it and tell me your opinion again?

Comment: Hi, I think you are over complicating things...  based on your updated question, you need to do multiple invoke-commands to get multiple variables and try not to distribute a script to a machine for remote execution

Comment: :sir i used your idea,and i could get all variables stored in the file named "Remote",then stored them in the excel file,                                                                                                New-PSSession -ComputerName $IP -Credential (Get-Credential) | Out-Null

Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -filepath C:\Users\Hkm\Desktop\Script\Remote.ps1 

$a = @( Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ScriptBlock { $variable1,$variable2,$variable3,$variable4} )

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

$a[0] #here you can see i can show the content of $variable1

Comment: Brilliant, remember you can put as many invoke-commands as you like and get as many separate variables back as you like.  If this has helped - please accept this as your answer or upvote it so that it can be identified and help others too.  Thanks.

Comment: i would like to thanks you a lot sir for helping me!i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

From your comment you say you have already got the results in a local variable $result so you just need to use the powershell file output functions to get it into an Excel-readable file.

A real .xlsx file would take a bit of work to create but you can user a .csv comma separated value file. There are examples at https://superuser.com/a/404096/1571 of a csv export or piping the command to an Out-File

Comment: Sir,i edited my request,please can you read it and tell me your opinion again?